# How to add keyboard in action sheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet

Is it possible add keyboard in action sheet?
If yes, how can I do? ... I would like to disable the background.
Thanks, Luigi.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You cannot put the system keyboard in an action sheet. You can either create your own keyboard and add it as a subview to an action sheet or change the style of the system keyboard.

Comment: `UIActionSheet` is for showing a set of buttons. That is all. Do not use it for anything else. If you better described what you really wanted to accomplish, someone could probably give you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think UIKeyBoard can not be added in ActionSheet but you achieve your goal but handling keyboard notifications...add the Keyboard will appear and will disappear notifications in your controller... 
on keyboard will appear add a subview of frame same as the parent view frame..and set its alpha 0.5...it will look like An ActionSheet is appearing and the background will automatically be disabled and on keyboard disappear remove that view from superview...you can add tap Gesture in the view you are adding..Hope so it will be answer of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add different controls to action sheets, like pickers and text views. However, as mentioned you can't add a keyboard.

If you want to customize what is shown when the keyboard is shown, you can slide controls with the keyboard, to make it look like they are part of the keyboard.

Alternatively you could create your own keyboard using buttons etc.